# Прозрачная таблица

Tags: html, css

Как сделать, чтоб таблица вылезала посередине, ссылка оставалась та же, всё, что сзади, было полупрозрачным? Пример привести не могу.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятнее всего, на всю страницу налаживается белый полупрозрачный блок, а уже сверху всплывающее окно.

**UPD:**

```css
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0.5
}

.popup {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-left: -250px;
  margin-right: -250px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="popup">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: да, скажи как сделать!

Comment: добавил пример

Comment: спс щяс проверю

Answer (score 1):

[opacity](http://htmlbook.ru/css/opacity)

> Определяет уровень прозрачности элемента веб-страницы. При частичной или полной прозрачности через элемент проступает фоновый рисунок или другие элементы, расположенные ниже полупрозрачного объекта.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3LhUQ/

Comment: Это не то. Вы не видите на скрине как? Сама таблица не прозрачная, а вокруг неё прозрачно!

Comment: Рамка прозрачная?

Comment: Нет, темная, а вокруг рамки - полупрозрачная.

Answer (score 1):

В css: `rgba(r, g, b, прозрачность от 0 до 1)`.